# Option Pricing Form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

For option pricing, we have a formula for the price of an option like the following:
$$\Phi(t,S_{t})$$ Where $S_{t}$ is the stock price.

Why not just write in a form of composite function:
$$\Phi(S(t))$$
Clearly they are different. But both of them are stochastic processes w.r.t time t. Why should we use the first one? What is the mathematical reason behind that, or the physical meaning under that(I believe it has some).

Comment: As an illuminating example, the value as provided by the Black-Scholes-Merton model for a European call option, $C(S_t,t)$, with strike $K$, and expiry time $T$ at time $t$ is given by $$C(S_t,t)=e^{-r(T-t)}(S_tN(d_1(S_t,t)-Ke^{r(T-t)}N(d_2(S_t,t))$$So, here we see the explicit time dependence.

Comment: @Dr.MV That is kind of interesting. They assume the formula of $\Phi(t,S_{t})$ and later get this result. If they assume another form like $\Phi(S(t))$, maybe they would find another form of option price, because the Ito formula applied to $\Phi$ would be different. My feeling's like, they may not find a beautiful or satisfying formula in other cases, thus they *assume* $\Phi(t,S_{t})$ is the best way.

Comment: Merton wrote some papers that developed properties of vanilla options that relied on strict arbitrage laws and not on any presupposed model for price stochastics.  And there are time dependency properties that are based only on these arbitrage laws.  So, there is explicit time dependence due to the "physical" nature of an option.  There are also price dependent properties that are based on arbitrage only.  Thus, an option depends on both time and state (i.e., price) as independent variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Merton's paper, "Theory of Rational Option Pricing," he developed properties of vanilla options (American and European) that relied on strict arbitrage laws and not on any presupposed model for price stochastics.

> **TIME DEPENDENCE**

There are time dependency properties that are based only on these arbitrage laws.  For example, Property $(4)$ of the paper states that for two call options with the same underlying asset and same strike, but different times to maturity, the value of the option with the greater time to maturity exceeds the value of the other.

Hence, the value of a call option increases with time to maturity $T$ or equivalently decreases with time $t$.  So, there is explicit time dependence due to the "physical" nature of an option.

> **PRICE DEPENDENCE**

There are also price dependent properties that are based on arbitrage only. Alongside these properties, Theorem $10$ of the paper proves that if the distribution of returns on the underlying price is independent of the price level, then the value of the option is a convex function of the underlying price.

---

Thus, an option depends on both time and price as independent variables.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Can I interpret in this way: $\Phi (t,S_{t})$ is a process determined by both t and St at the same time, but $\Phi (S(t))$ is a process that either determined by St or by t, cannot be both?

Comment: Well, the second shows that $\Phi$ depends on $S$ as an independent variable and that $S_t$ depends on $t$.  The first shows that $\Phi$ depends on $S_t$ and $t$ as independent variables and that $S_t$ depends on $t$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that we decide that $S_t$ is a variable by itself, and that we may have a payoff that is a function of t, independently of $S_t$. The second expression is just saying that the payoff is only function of the underlying $S_t$, which is also a function of time.
For example , $\phi(t,S_t)=S_t-t^2$, will not fit into your second definition but in the first one.

Comment: So for the simplest BS model, we could write the second way? Since $S(t)$ is determined by GBM, thus S and t are not independent. And for Euro option pricing, it only decided by $S(T)$.

Comment: Most payoff are just functions of the stock, not the time. Think about the function that returns the payoff. In a European option with strike K, and maturity T, the payoff function is $\phi(x)=max(x-K,0)$. We dont really care about the time, but we care about the value of S at time T, as we replace x in our function by $S_T$.

Comment: $S(T)$ is obviously a function of T, but if we have the distrubution of S(T),which is also a function of T, that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The payoff may not depend on time, however, the option value, at time $t$, has a particular dependence on time $t$ through the discount factor, specifically, the discount factor is a function of time $t$, or defined by a term structure.

Comment: It also has an explicit dependence through the "time-scaled" volatility parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV for your interesting addition.

Comment: And for more exotic options, the possibility of early exercise (e.g., barrier options) creates an even more interesting time dependence that manifests itself in a change of boundary conditions in the PDE description.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV. Those are also interesting scenarios.

Comment: Of course, for the standard barrier option, the analog of the Black-Scholes formula can be expressed in terms of the corresponding vanilla option with scaled or inverted input parameters.  The explicit time dependence appears in the discount factor and scaled volatility.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following reasons to do that. First of all as dynamical system, its evolution function is explicitly dependent on $t$. Secondly It is explicitly dendent on $S$. For instance you can suppose $S$ to be something not dependent on time(like something trivial). Next , a convinient tool of stochastic analysis is Ito formula. And $S$ is almost always defined through some Stochastic differential equation, Ito formula can be used to derive the stochastic differential equation of $\Phi(t, S_t)$.
And last. It is sometimes convenient to look at non stochastic PDE(or ODE)-s. There $S_{t}$ is almost always substituted with dummy variable $x$
In the form you have proposed, there is now dependence on t. Which merely means that if for some outcome $\omega$, we have $S_{t_{1}}= S_{t_{2}}$, than $\Phi(t_{1})=\Phi(t_{2})$, which is not always true.

Maybe I'm wrong.